# Quantum mechanics between proton & electron but not electron and positron

Tags: photons, orbitals

An electron approaching a proton gives off the hydrogen spectra. An electron approaching a positron does not give off the spectrum of hydrogen. Why? Both scenarios are -1 charge approach a +1 charge. One set of charges are found in spdf orbitals. The other set just annihilate into a photon. Why the difference? How do the proton electron pair know they are not a electron positron pair?

Comment: Today's vocabulary word is *"[positronium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium)"*.

Comment: Or to be less facetious, your question is founded on a misunderstanding: electrons and positrons *will* form atoms. They just don't last long because they will annihilate shortly after the atom falls into a s-state if not sooner.

Comment: Don't forget the mass difference. An proton is massive enough that we can almost treat the electron as orbiting a fixed central potential. In positronium this is definitely not the case.

Comment: A proton is *not* a point particle (it has sub-structure), whereas a positron is a point particle. In fact, a positron is the anti-particle of an electron, whereas a proton is *not*. A proton is made up of quarks and gluons (all strongly interacting), whereas a positron is *not* (it has no sub-structure). A proton is much heavier than a positron. etc etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

@dmckee is correct: the positronium atom indeed does have spdf energy levels. What threw me off was missing the fact that the s orbital does have a finite probability of 'collision' between the antiparticles and thus their annihilation. I was viewing the s sate as a Bohr 'orbital' where the electron could not spiral into the positron because it could not radiate away energy continuously but only in quanta. QED explains all the energy levels and lifetimes. Sorry to have missed the probability of electron positron meeting.